# need help with ubuntu 18.04, keeps freezing

Tags: 18.04

have a new build here ryzen 7 2700x on a gigabyte b450m- ds3h, just installed ubuntu 18.04 LTS and the installation worked fine then after a while it froze, did hard reset and keept on freezing so did some searching and found problems with c6 and Power Supply Idle Control. so changed Power Supply Idle Control to typical current idle and disabled global c-state idle control. but still freezes. anyone have any experince with this problem or have any tips or ideas on how to fix it ??

Comment: if it crashes at random moments it generally is a hardware failure. Please check /var/log/ for possible error notices (search for CRITICAL in the logs with the newest logging added so `ls -ltr /var/log/*` and examine the bottom file(s). syslog is likely to be the one to look at. You could also do a memtest from grub menu or the live session.

Comment: I know it is hardware problem, many others have with ryzen, and what i did have worked for them, if i check the log what am i supposed to do next after that.